# html source in http request

Tags: http, iis

I'm running a .Net based website and record in a database all unhandled errors. For the last several weeks (but never before that I noticed) I've been getting "URL too long" errors.  The odd part is that the requested URL contains HTML source from my home page, it starts:

http://adoptuskids.org/_inc/1267/js/jquery-slideshow-mar [/ul] [/li] [li class="children"][a hr

- I truncated the above, it continues to a length of 1326 characters
- I also did a little text substitution "<" to "[" and removed some white space
- in the error request it is character for character out of my source

This appears to be a request for an asset within the HEAD of the page:

[script src='/_inc/1267/js/jquery-slideshow-marquee.js' type='text/javascript'][/script]

By investigating IIS logs I've determined that the users who encountered this error were surfing the site in a normal manner both before and after the error.

Does anyone have any idea how this could be happening?